# PDFSharp - Fast Web View feature

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

Any one tried implementing fast web view using PDFSharp in C#.Net.
Kindly let me know how it can be achieved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do You mean, You wnat to show PDF in web brower?

Comment: Not only to web browser, but i want to compress the PDF using PDFSharp so that it takes minimal time to load in browser,also consume less space

Comment: Voted down?, please explain me

Comment: it is not me. But Your question is not good for SO. You must show Us what You do aleready a ask the concrete question

Answer (score 0):

PDFsharp does not (yet) support fast web view (which basically re-arranges elements in the PDF file so that partially downloaded PDF files can show the first page earlier).

PDFsharp has some options that allow to create smaller PDF files.

See this post in the PDFsharp forum:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=9647#p9647

If you use the PDFsharp source code for your project, make sure you ship a RELEASE build (the DEBUG build creates much larger PDF files by default for debugging purposes).